# Array formula only returns the first value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I'm trying to use an array function in Excel, the formula is to return the value of filtered table. This is my formula:

```
{=INDEX(A:A,MIN(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A2,ROW(A2:A31)-ROW(A2),0)),ROW(A2:A31))))}
```

The problem is the returned value is only the first result, i.e. if after filter the first cell is `A9` when I drag down the formula it will only return `A9` value in all cells. This is my first try at using array function so I don't know what to check, I think the formula itself is correct but because this is my first try maybe I miss something. I already press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for validating.

Actually my goal is to return values of cells that meet certain criteria, I tried using different function but because it's too complicated then I tried using Excel built in filter but because it only hides the cells that doesn't meet the criteria, it won't work with my other formula that use the filtered value. I would prefer solutions that are not too complicated or using VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question a while ago and get a good reply from [Ron Coderre](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/microsoft.public.excel.worksheet.functions/lylugThaE7U)

He suggested both an array and non-array formula solution.  The formulas are complex.  I offer a very simple, intuitive, approach that uses simple, non-array formulas with a helper column.

Say we have data in columns **A** and **B**.  In **C2** enter:

```
=SUBTOTAL(3,$A$2:$A2)
```

and copy downward:

[image]

The helper column is a simple set of sequential values.  We now filter for *dog*:

[image]

The helper has adjusted to remain a simple sequential sequence!  This allows us to use a standard `MATCH()/INDEX()` approach to grab the visible data.  In `Sheet2` cell **A1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),Sheet1!C:C,0)),"")
```

and copy downward:

[image]

If you can't use a helper column, try one of the Coderre formulas.

Comment: I tried your formula and it works, it even help as reference to fix my other formula. I haven't found what make my previous formula doesn't work though, but your is simpler so i will use it for now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use transpose function before index. Or return the function horizontally.